# Route website through Android app?

Tags: android, proxy, filter, web-traffic

I'm trying to create a web filter app that will intercept an incoming website(one that is being browsed to) and redirect it's data to my app.  Then it will compare the site to certain criteria and display it if it passes.

Basically, I want to turn my app into a proxy of sorts.  How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to build your own browser.  Use a simple webview and build the functionality you want around it.